# Categorical variable that is both nominal and ordinal

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, data-preprocessing

In a dataset with house prices I encountered the variable BsmtCond that describes the general condition of the basement. It takes 6 values:

```
   Ex   Excellent
   Gd   Good
   TA   Typical
   Fa   Fair
   Po   Poor
   NA   No Basement
```

I would like to find the best representation of this data to feed it into machine learning algorithm(s). It is not ordinal, since there is no consistent way to assign a number to 'NA' (where do you put it on "Excellent -- Poor" scale?). On the other hand, one hot encoding loses some information (like the fact that "Excellent > Good > Typical > Fair > Poor") that might be useful for developing a proper model.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Depends what you want to do with the data - could you please edit the question to explain?

Comment: This looks ordinal to me.  "NA" means not applicable: it's not one of the possible values on the scale.

Comment: Thanks, but that's still quite vague - or perhaps presupposing there's one encoding that'll suit any role played by the variable in any algorithm. Is the algorithm for supervised or unsupervised learning at least? If supervised, is `BsmtCond` the predictor or the response?